# Open teamspeak server through extension button

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension project and one of the button of the popup must open my TeamSpeak server on click.

The final HTML code of my button is :

```
<a href="ts3server://MYSERVER" target="_blank" id="teamspeak"></a>
```

Issue is my button open a new blank page with the address "ts3server://MYSERVER". If I manually copy and paste "ts3server://MYSERVER" in Chrome, it open TeamSpeak software as wished.

Comment: What happens if you remove `target="_blank"`?

Comment: I've tried to remove it, or to replace it by whatever I could but result is that button doesn't open anything anymore. Only target I've found which make button do something is '_blank', and it do it badly.

Comment: If popup is a restricted secure zone, shouldn't other buttons not work too? I have also buttons to open facebook, twitter, etc and they work well.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I hope what you've said will work. I will test it as soon as I'm at home.

Comment: It's not about popup, if I do "window.open(MYSERVER);" in content script it also open a blank page.

Comment: background script*

Comment: Well, "chrome.tabs.create({'url': MYSERVER});" works better.

Comment: I resolved it almost with "var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); link.onclick = function() { bg.chrome.tabs.create({'url': MYSERVER}); }", It open teamspeak, but also the same blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding (and removing) an invisible iframe.

```
function openExternalLink(uri) {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = uri;
  iframe.style.display = "none"; // Make sure it's hidden
  document.body.appendChild(iframe); // This will trigger load => external request
  iframe.remove(); // Cleanup
}
```

You need to create a button and add a click handler that calls this.

No need to disturb existing tabs for that.

Comment: Without seeing how you did the rest, can't tell what's wrong. Perhaps it's a good opportunity for a new question.